# Nilpotency of Maximal Ideal of Local Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

What are the implications of the maximal ideal of a local ring $(A,m,k)$ being nilpotent? For example, $A$ is Artinian if and only if it is Noetherian. Any other interesting implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nakayama's Lemma holds for arbitrary modules (without f.g. assumption): $M/\mathfrak{m}M=0$ implies $M=0$. Of course this is purely formal and holds for every nilpotent ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The ring then has a unique prime ideal (the maximal ideal) and every element in the ring is either a unit or nilpotent.

Comment: How can I prove it? Maybe by using the prime avoidance lemma?

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathfrak m^t=0$, then $\mathfrak m = \mathrm{rad}(\mathfrak m^t)=\mathrm{rad}(0)$. Since $\mathrm{rad}(0)$ is the intersection of all prime ideals, then $\mathfrak m$ is the only prime ideal. Hence $$\dim A = \mathrm{codim}\ \mathfrak m =0.$$

Answer (score 1):

If so then any $A$-module is flat if and only if it is projective if and only if it is free. See $(3.G)$ in [*Commutative Algebra*](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0/Matsumura,_Commutative_Algebra,1980.pdf) by Hideyuki Matsumura.